# blackberry retranslate.onLanguageChanged isn't work

Tags: qt, c++11, blackberry-10

My application isn't work normally

This is my code

```
    Label {
        // The label text is set using the qsTr() function to support translation.
        // and Retranslate.onLanguageChanged will force the string to update
        // if language change happens while the app is running.
        text: qsTr("hello world") + Retranslate.onLanguageChanged

        // The label text style.
        textStyle.base: SystemDefaults.TextStyles.BigText
        textStyle.color: Color.create("#085861")
    }
```

and

```
void ApplicationUI::onSystemLanguageChanged() {
QCoreApplication::instance()->removeTranslator(mTranslator);

QString localeString = QLocale().name();
QString fileName = QString("FirstProject_%1").arg(localeString);

if (mTranslator->load(fileName, "app/native/qm")) {
    QCoreApplication::instance()->installTranslator(mTranslator);
}
}
```

Following project work properly.

http://downloads.blackberry.com/upr/developers/downloads/sampleapps/cascades/hellocascades.zip

I think my source code and link's project's source code are perfectly same.

but my project, translation method isn't working....

Comment: You need to be more specific, how doesn't it work. What is the expected output, and what does it produce instead.

Comment: do you have a .ts file? This has nothing to do with C++11 as BlackBerry10 doesn't support C++11

Comment: when i build bb project, qml text -> hello world.   in my device -> the text "hello world" is translated in korean.

Comment: but when i build my project, translation method isn't work.  "hello world" is  printed "hello world"....

Comment: I'm very stuppid man. I found a problem. I had to check translation folder.  thanks a lot